# Graphing a Triangle Given the Side Lengths/Angle Measures

Tags: trigonometry

Are there any other ways than converting from polar to rectangular coordinates to graph the three points of a triangle on a Cartesian coordinate system if you are given the values of all three side lengths and the angle measures? Assume that the origin point of angle A is 0, 0.

P.S. I am only 14 and just getting into calculus. So, if possible, try and keep the advanced mathematics to a minimum.

Comment: Can you also place the side AB on the positive x-axis?

Comment: Yes. That would make the origin point of angle C equal to AB, 0

Comment: Have you learned the equation of circles yet? $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and more generally, $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure I can see how that's relevant.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comments above. You actually don't need the angles if you can put AB on the x-axis. I will paste a picture below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the picture:

[image]

Suppose you know the length of the three sides as shown above. All you need to do it to find the coordinates of $C$, knowing the length $a,b$.

Let the coordinates of $C$ be $(x,y)$. Then by Pythagorean theorem,

$$x^2+y^2=b^2\quad (1)\\
(c-x)^2+y^2=a^2 \Rightarrow x^2-2cx+c^2+y^2=a^2 \quad(2)$$

Now subtract (2) from (1):

$$2cx-c^2=b^2-a^2\Rightarrow x=\frac{b^2-a^2+c^2}{2c}$$

You can then find $y$ using (1) or (2).